# How to fill a circle with an image with css and html?

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my image is not filling out the entire circle. It's only a smaller
version of the image that is showing in my circle. I need the image to fill out the entire circle. How can I do that?

```
<figure [ngStyle]="{ 'box-shadow': '0px 5px 5px 0px red'  }">
  <img [src]="'https://img2.androidappsapk.co/115/b/1/a/com.ludicside.mrsquare.png'" alt="resource.Name">
</figure>
```

My css

```css
figure {
  float: left;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* display:inline-block; */
  padding: 10px;
  height: 66px;
  width: 66px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px blue;
}

figure img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://img2.androidappsapk.co/115/b/1/a/com.ludicside.mrsquare.png" alt="resource.Name"> </figure>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way by giving `width: 100%;` and `overflow: hidden;` to the parent.

```css
figure {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 66px;
  width: 66px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://img2.androidappsapk.co/115/b/1/a/com.ludicside.mrsquare.png" alt="resource.Name"> </figure>
```

Comment: This looks good. Is there anything that can be done about the white showing on the sides? if you look you can see on the right and left side

Comment: @TerranceJackson your image is having a gap towards the borders, if you take it off, it is solved. And if you cant, I suggest the `figure` can have the same background as the image red.

Comment: Try `background-image-size: 130%;`. That should be the correct amount to ensure that image fills it's containing circle without losing too much of the edges.